# Транслировать sql запрос в запрос hql

Tags: hibernate

Как перевести sql запрос в запрос hql:

```
select * from t1 where (a1 < a2 and a3 > a4) is null;
```

Comment: @robin_2005, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Делаю:
Query query1 = session.createQuery("from t1 a where ( a.a1 < a.a2 and a.a3 > a.a4) is null");

В результате получаю такую ошибку:
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: and near line 1, column 43 [from main.java.table.t1 a where ( a.a1 < a.a2 and a.a3 > a.a4) is null")]